# mvn clean install using java 1.5 or 1.6

Tags: maven

When I do mvn clean install, I get this error:

annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(try -source 1.5 to enable annotations)

But where do I put this -source 1.5 command? I tried all permutations with mvn clean install and couldn't get it to work. So I tried putting compilation in my pom, like this:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

But that didn't work either.. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Ah, actually using 1.5 instead of 1.6 and it works fine now. OK...

Comment: Ah, so you answered your own question.  You should add your answer to the question and give yourself some credit for figuring it out.

Comment: The solution is to remove `<scope>test</scope>` from Junit Plugin. Because it is only checking src/java/test not src/java/main. And if i am not wrong you have dependency in that folder also. That will do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the compiler plugin is 2.3.2. This version seems to support 1.6 as both version and target parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring the compiler plugin, which requires supplying a version, you can 
set `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
   ....
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
```